# How to tag questions related to C family of languages (C, C++, Objective-C)?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions

I regularly work on different projects using the C, C++ and Objective-C languages. I know it is distracting when people assume C and C++ are the same and incorrectly tag their question as such when it doesn't apply (I've been guilty of that). I now understand the differences between each language and when a subject applies to all or one of these topics.

When I ask a question that is relevant to all 3 languages should I tag them as such? Is there a "C Family" tag I should use instead? Should I only tag them as C (lowest common denominator for all 3)?

**EDIT**

Example: Should a question about how to use bit flags have a C, C++ and Objective-C version? Or should one question exist tagged as all 3.

Comment: It it's truly relevant to all, tag them with all. But you better be sure it is. If the particular language is completely irrelevant however, then language-agnostic (I think) is the correct tag.

Comment: Unless you're an expert in all three languages, be prepared for some of the answers to point out differences that you didn't know about.

Comment: @KeithThompson That definitely happens, especially with subtle implementation differences between C and C++. I feel like I am an expert in Objective-C and C, the cases where it happens is usually C++. Maybe when I am less sure, I should avoid including the C++.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is all assuming that the question you have isn't expressly about differences between the various languages, but about some code you've written which is going to be compiled in a specific manner.

Objective-C is a superset of C; any legal C is legal ObjC. You should use [objc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objc) only if that *language* is an important factor in your question -- you're using objects, sending messages, or using some other feature that isn't present in C. If your code doesn't require ObjC, then C is almost certainly the correct tag to use.

C and C++, as I understand it, are far more divergent than C and ObjC (cf. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74538/disallow-the-tagging-of-questions-with-both-c-and-c-tags?rq=1). They each have their own official standard specifications, and I would be very careful about conflating or combining the two. If you're compiling as C++, I don't think that [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) is appropriate.

For completeness, there's also Objective-C++, which -- as the name implies -- is an amalgamation of ObjC and C++. This is its own special breed, and has its own tag, although given its *explicitly* hybrid status, I think it's likely to be more fitting in this case to also include one or the other of [objc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objc) or [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), depending on the exact nature of your question.

I think that limiting your tagging to only one of the three you've mentioned produces the most focused and helpful set of answers.

Comment: I can see this point of view as well. So say something like "how do flags work" (I asked this when I first started). The technique is used frequently in C, C++, and objc. Do you still think that the best tag for this would be C?

Comment: If you're compiling as C or ObjC, yes, that's what I would say. If compiling as C++, then [tag:c++].

Comment: @JoshCaswell as I mentioned, I may need to learn about the technique, but I regularly use all 3 languages. "What im compiling" depends on the day of the week.

Comment: The results of the technique are dependent on your compilation, though. C isn't the "lowest common denominator" for C++.

Comment: Not always, and especially not for C and Objective-C. What I mean by common denominator is that people can saftely assume that something tagged as C will (most likely) work in their C or objective-c projects, where as the opposite is not true.

Answer (score 8):

C and C++ are different beasts. So if the question requires an answer for C++, tag it so. Ditto for C. Ditto for "whatever"

But do not tag for both. That makes no sense. Would you tag a question for an answer in Japanese and French at the same time?

Comment: I get what your saying, but that is a horrible analogy. There also is a lot of cases not clear cut "relevant here but not there".

Comment: @JustinMeiners I think the analogy works very well. Most questions would only be tagged [tag:french] or only [tag:japanese], except for a small minority which are about translating between the two languages. Similarly very few questions should be tagged both [tag:c] and [tag:c++], only questions about interoperability between the two (e.g. how to call a C++ function from C).

Comment: @Gilles So if someone has a question about flags we should have a C, C++, and Objective-C version of the same question and answer? I don't think speech languages compare to programing languages, and french and japanese are not similar at all.

Comment: @JustinMeiners: take French and Spanish then. Very similar languages, still there are _faux amis_ and structures that work in one language but not the other.

Comment: It _can_ be valid to tag both C and C++.  As long as the code is valid in both.  But don't tag something with C++ and then use structs everywhere or tag something with C that won't compile with a C compiler (e.g. has namespaces, classes, etc, etc).

Answer (score 5):

**Do not tag such questions with all 3 tags.**

C++ is *not* a superset of C, it is a completely different language with a shared history and similar syntax. The answers may be completely different. And even in the case of Objective-C, which *is* a strict superset of C, the idioms are not necessarily the same. You *could* write C code in Objective-C, but then you're not writing Objective-C, you're writing C. Support for that is an important feature of the language, but it is irrelevant in our tagging system.

Consider the example you gave: manipulating a bit flag. The code to do that in C is simply:

```c
unsigned int bitField = 0U;
bitField |= flag;   // set a bit
bitField &= ~flag;  // clear a bit
```

That would be the correct answer if the question were tagged [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c).
However, were the question to be tagged [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), you could expect a very different answer; namely:

> Use the `bitset<N>` container class provided by the standard library.

That answer would, of course, *not* be valid if posted to a question with the [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) tag, since the C standard library provides no such functionality. But not only is it provided by the C++ standard library, it is the *preferred* way of manipulating bit fields in C++ code. Sure, you could do it "the C way", but then you are not doing it "the C++ way" and have misleading tagged your question with the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag . You should have used [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) if you want to get answers on the C way of doing things.

If you don't find that convincing, and still feel strongly that C, C++, and Objective-C are so similar as to merit this abuse of the tag system, consider the C# language. You *certainly* wouldn't dream of tagging the question [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), would you? But why not? C# shares a history with the C language, and a whole lot of its syntax. Certainly you could check if a bit flag is set using the same code in C# as you would in C. The only thing you'd need to change would be `unsigned int` to `uint`, a commonly used typedef even in the C world:

```cs
uint bitField = 0U;
bitField |= flag;   // set a bit
bitField &= ~flag;  // clear a bit
```

So what do you do? **Use the tag that most accurately describes the either the language you're working in, or the language whose idioms you want to adopt.** Ignore the fact that the answer might *also* be the same for some other language, or set of languages. You could easily be wrong. And even if you're not, it is quite irrelevant that Java experts may also be able to answer the question.

If the question is language-neutral, or you are looking for solutions that go beyond the idioms and idiosyncracies of particular languages, use the [language-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic) tag. Please do not use all of the tags for all of the languages that you might have some tangential applicability to your question.

Comment: "*But not only is it provided by the C++ standard library, it is the preferred way of manipulating bit fields in C++ code.*" Citation needed. Admittedly, I see plenty of "C in C++ code", but even among more hardcore C++ programmers, you will see plenty of unsigned integer bitfields. For example, I don't see Qt or other major C++ frameworks adopting `bitset` as the way to handle bitfields.

Comment: And plenty of C++ programmers use C-style strings. That doesn't mean all questions about C-style string manipulation should have the C++ tag. I think the usage you describe is mostly a force of habit thing, or possibly a misguided sense that a container class would be "too slow" and they'd better do the manipulation themselves. I'm quite sure it misses the point here. @nicol

Comment: My point is that "*the language whose idioms you want to adopt*" are defined by the *users* of the language. And code that uses unsigned ints is very much an idiom in common usage among C++ programmers. So it's not a good example of an idiom that is legal C++ but would warrant the C tag. A better example would be most uses of `malloc/free`.

Comment: So that specific example may not work for C++. Should the bit flag question still be tagged C and Objective-C as that is the way it is done in both languages? If so it gives precedent to include all 3 tags on questions that it is truly relevant. If not it warrants potentially 2-3 copies of each question for each language.

Comment: I think you should have separate questions for each language, if someone wants to ask them. That's not the kind of duplication that we're against. Because it isn't duplication at all. As I pointed out, it is likely that the answers will be different even when one might not expect them to be.

Comment: Bad example.  In 14 years I've never seen a bitset used in C++ code.  I wouldn't say it was wrong to, but I would never write code using one, and I'd probably tell a code review not to either-  nobody has ever heard of it, nobody understands it, and they do understand the int.  I get your point only 1 of the 3 should be tagged, but I think any of the 3 is fine for that question.  And I'd reject an edit changing the tag from C++ to C as it is valid C++.

Answer (score 2):

Experts in C might not be experts in C++ and so on. Hence tagging them with all the appropriate languages is a good decision, provided it really is a question that is relevant to all the languages.
All the best.

Comment: But usually, it's *not* relevant to all three.  It's relevant to one and an ignorant user thinks they're related enough that any will do.

Comment: @djechlin my question is about the things that are relevant to all 3.

Comment: @JustinMeiners example? I bet most the overwhelming majority of questions you would think are all three, are really just one with the other two tacked on.

Comment: @djechlin Personal examples (old): how to use bit flags, 2.0 vs 2.0f syntax, macro function rules, advantages of explicitly sized types, etc. I think a lot of concern about grouping the 3 is related to implementation differences, but there are numerous questions out there about simply how to use language features.

Comment: @JustinMeiners SO problems are expected to be about actual problems you face. So if you're programming in C and have that question...  it's a C tag.  If you're used to programming in C and are explicitly asking if there's a difference between C and C++, that's a case you could argue both but I would still lean the language you're actually using.  Just because all languages support the feature doesn't mean it should be tagged with all of them.

Comment: @djechlin I think the precedent of a repository of knowledge and immediately answering your own question says that they don't have to be actual problems, but lets say your right. As I mentioned I use all those languages pretty much all the time (sometimes in the same day), when I ask a question it is often related to questions I have about all 3 languages. If I knew the answer in one I would know it in all.

Comment: @djechlin once again, should those question examples have 3 different versions? or be tagged for 3 different langauges?

Comment: @JustinMeiners in general I'm saying people have a strong tendency to over-estimate relevance when in situations related to C and one of these other languages. In your case, from what you've said, maybe not. Can you link an actual question? This is too hypothetical for me to give any stronger opinion on.

Comment: @djechlin I would agree with you there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10221486/drawbacks-of-using-explicitly-sized-types-in-c-family-languages http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643681/how-do-flags-work-in-c-family-languages