# Tagging [swift]/[objective-c] for framework/language-agnostic related questions

Tags: discussion, tags, duplicate-questions, duplicate-answers

I recently edited [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36650189/how-to-use-small-caps) on the basis of thinking that consensus was  framework/language-agnostic questions should not include tags for unrelated things such as language, IDE, etc. It was pointed in the comments, that I should not interfere with language tags. One of the reasons was the `[swift]` tag's description:

> Use this tag **only** for questions that are specific to Swift language features, *or those that require code in the language*. **Use the related tags** [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios), [osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx), [apple-watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-watch), [tag: tvos], [cocoa-touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocoa-touch), and [cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocoa) **for (language-agnostic) questions about the platforms or frameworks**.

(Emphasis mine)

I think this description is problematic. The description asks users to only use the tag when the question is related to language specific issues, otherwise the framework and platform tags should be used. A later edit added the italic part, but I think it makes little sense given the other instructions (emphasised in bold).

Moreover, I think allowing users to limit their questions to a specific language for such framework-related issues, which are already widely answered, would create many many duplicate questions, where the only difference is the language used to call framework methods. For example, to the question above, the following are answers to duplicate questions:

[Typesetting a font in small caps on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941984/typesetting-a-font-in-small-caps-on-ios)

[Does CoreText support Small Caps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810409/does-coretext-support-small-caps)

In the original question, among the things I edited out, the following remark existed from the OP:

> Again, please don't mark this as a duplicate question and then link to an Objective C answer. This has not been answered for Swift.

The OP is aware other answers exist, yet chose to create a duplicate question. With the smallest of effort, the OP would get his answer from already existing answers, including the two I provided.

Should such questions really be allowed? Is the tag description above accurate? Especially with such related languages as Swift and Objective C when it comes to iOS/OS X frameworks, I think language alone should not allow for duplicate questions.

Comment: Closely related: [Is it acceptable to post answers in Swift on iOS/OS X questions marked with the ObjC tag and vice versa?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285258) Also: [How to tag questions related to C family of languages C, C++, ObjC?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252434) Also also: [Should Swift and ObjC tags never be used together?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315714)

Comment: `I think this description is problematic.` It's a wiki, feel free to edit it.

Comment: @JAL I want to get a feeling first of what the community things, before editing this way or the other. I always thought language agnostic questions should not be plastered with tags about the language. But I may be wrong.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Thanks for posting these. I am familiar with them, and where I was basing my edits.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that "consensus [is] framework/language-agnostic questions should not include tags for unrelated things such as language". But not everyone knows that (and probably some people disagree). The italic part looks like it was copied over from [tag:objc]'s excerpt, where I originally added that verbiage as a sort of compromise position. I know that the "pure" idea of "only questions [that are about the language itself get this tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62669/)" would never stick.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you want to second-guess the OP of the question so much? If he tagged the question with Objective-C and posted code written in Objective-C... why should you *want* to answer in some other language? No matter how "related" it may be?

Answer the question the OP asked. Don't bother yourself about trying to divine what he really wants or trying to decide if a Swift answer would be more appropriate or whatever. Just provide the information the OP asked for.

Or don't; if you don't want to answer an Objective-C question, just move on to the next one. But you should not arbitrarily decide that a Swift answer is appropriate to a question that explicitly asked for Objective-C.

Just like you shouldn't provide a C answer to a question that is tagged C++. Or at the very least, not a C answer that can't be compiled as C++.

Answer (score 1):

While for some users the conversion of an Objective-C answer to Swift is a piece of cake, for others it isn't. A couple of features, e.g. the Smalltalk-like messaging syntax, is confusing to people without a lot of Objective-C hours under their belt.

Of course, it would be better if the Objective-C question would also contain a Swift answer, but if the OP is not able to write one, he can either put a bounty on the original question, or ask a new question.

In the same train of thought: you can use both C# and Visual Basic to create .NET programs. Does that mean each VB.NET question is a duplicate of a C# .NET one?

Comment: At the moment, you can't realistically be an Apple-platform dev without knowing some ObjC. This may (will) shift in the future, but there is _so much_ existing infrastructure based around ObjC that I find "I can't read ObjC, I need an answer in Swift code" to be frankly verging on a (rud) "do my work for me" kind of attitude. There are intricacies involved in moving between the two (like the way Swift changes/shortens method names), but those should be coverable _in general_, as something everyone should also have a grasp on.

Comment: VB.NET and C# are not _that_ different. If two questions asks very specifically about the .NET Framework in these two languages, I am really not sure if the questions should not be merged. And as Josh says, the relationship between Swift and ObjC is much more interwoven, even more so than the first-party .NET languages.